# React Native: change component colour using TouchableOpacity onPress()

Tags: react-native

I'm making a to-do list to display on a page where the user can click on an icon to mark the task as done, in which the background colour of the corresponding task changes. The issue I'm having is I reuse the 'task' component and cannot specify which component's background should change colour. Hence, clicking any of the icons changes only one component's background colour. GIF of what I mean is below:

[Only one component is changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2kKy.gif)

My code is as follows:

```
export default function GoalItems(props) {
  const goals = props.goals;

  if (goals == 1) {
    return <Goal goal="Goal 1" />;
  } else if (goals == 2) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Goal goal="Goal 1" />
        <View style={{marginVertical: 15}} />
        <Goal goal="Goal 2" />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Goal goal="Goal 1" />
        <View style={{marginVertical: 15}} />
        <Goal goal="Goal 2" />
        <View style={{marginVertical: 15}} />
        <Goal goal="Goal 3" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function Goal(props) {
  const text = props.goal;
  const [checkBox, setCheckBox] = useState(false);
  const [checkBoxValue, setCheckBoxValue] = useState(
    'ios-checkmark-circle-outline',
  );
  const [iconColour, setIconColour] = useState('#FF1744');
  const [goalColour, setGoalColour] = useState('#64B5F6');

  onPressCheckBox = () => {
    setCheckBox(!checkBox);
    if (checkBox) {
      setCheckBoxValue('ios-checkmark-circle');
      setIconColour('#1ABC9C');
      setGoalColour('#1ABC9C');
    } else {
      setCheckBoxValue('ios-checkmark-circle-outline');
      setIconColour('#FF1744');
      setGoalColour('#64B5F6');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.goalContainer}>
      <View style={[{backgroundColor: goalColour}, styles.goal]}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressCheckBox()}>
        <Icon
          name={checkBoxValue}
          size={40}
          style={styles.checkbox}
          color={iconColour}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And the I just render `<GoalItems goals={num_of_goals} />` in my main app page. I know its poorly coded with the if statements but I'm not sure how to return X amount of `<GoalItems />` given `num_of_goals`, but that's a separate issue...

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason is asynchronous.
When you call `setCheckBox(!checkBox)` you must wait to it working. When it done, you continue handle new state.

```js
onPressCheckBox = () => {
      setCheckBox(!checkBox)
};
useEffect(() => {
     if (checkBox) {
      setCheckBoxValue('ios-checkmark-circle');
      setIconColour('#1ABC9C');
      setGoalColour('#1ABC9C');
    } else {
      setCheckBoxValue('ios-checkmark-circle-outline');
      setIconColour('#FF1744');
      setGoalColour('#64B5F6');
    }
 }, [])
```